# Взятие названия вызванного метода в качестве строки-аргумента

Tags: python, классы, вконтакте, методы, requests

Предположим, есть объект `Foo` класса `Bar`. В этом классе нет реализованной функции, например, с названием `methodsClass.method`. Я хочу, чтобы при вызывании `Foo.methodClass.method` вызывалась какая-то другая функция, которая принимала бы `methodClass.method` как строку-аргумент.

Откуда у меня возник такой вопрос на практике: есть модуль `vk` для *Python* (https://github.com/voronind/vk), который обращается к API ВКонтакте. Работа с ним довольна проста, например:

```
vkapi.messages.send(user_id=receiver_id, message=msg)
```

Но в коде этого модуля нет методов с методами VK API (в т.ч. `messages.send`). Как я понял, этот самый `messages.send` и аргументы `user_id=receiver_id, message=msg` как-то задаются, как параметр для `requests.get()`. Вопрос: как это реализовано? Про что нужно прочитать?

Comment: Самому интересно узнать решение этого вопроса. Может, использовать что-то вроде этого: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184281/python-dynamic-function-creation-with-custom-names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то у классов python есть возможность "подхватывать" неопределенные методы. Например так:

```
class Class_(object):
    def test(self):
        print(f"Defined method {self} called.")
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def catch(*args):
            print(f"Undefined method {name} called. Calling it as an external function.")
            if args:
                res=eval(f"{name}{args}") # eval - Исключительно для примера,
                                          # потому как дыра в безопасности кода.
                return res
        return catch

a = Class_()
a.test() # метод определен в классе
a.print("Testing undefined class method!") # метод не определен в классе
```

Получим:

```
Defined method <__main__.Class_ object at 0x0460F750> called.
Undefined method print called. Calling it as an external function.
Testing undefined class method!
```

Comment: Приблизительно понял, но всё равно не могу понять, как это реализовано в https://github.com/voronind/vk, там ничего подобного не вижу, но, думаю дело в методе \_\_getattr__, надо получше разобраться с ним.